# How can I add relation values to a serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to return many thousands of results along with one attribute from a relation.
I tried including the value in the fields array but got the following error:

> Field name `checklist__location__latitude` is not valid for model
> `Sighting`.

Is there a way to add the `latitude` value to each sighting object? I'm cautious of adding too much overhead to the returned results (they could get very large, so I want the JSON to be as minimal as possible), and I don't want to iterate over every object to attach the value after retrieval from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `annotate()` and `Subquery()` from Django ORM for this task. Here's example from my code which will show what I mean. It adds multiple fields based on data from other tables. These fields can be serialized using DRF, as usual.

```py
class TaskListAnnotateMixin(GenericAPIView):
    """
    Annotates Task QuerySet with additional fields depending on logged in user:
    - comments_count, category_title, new_comments_count, is_favorite, is_acquainted, author first/second/last name,
      author avatar url.
    """

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Annotate QuerySet. Exclude archived tasks and private tasks of other users.
        Apply `order_by()` based on GET parameters.
        """
        task_list = Task.objects.all()

        # Exclude archived tasks
        task_list = task_list.exclude(is_archived=True)

        # Exclude private tasks of other users
        task_list = task_list.exclude(~Q(author=self.request.user) & Q(is_private=True))

        # Count non-archived comments for each task
        task_list = task_list.annotate(
            comments_count=Count("comments", filter=Q(comments__is_archived=False))
        )

        # Add category title
        task_list = task_list.annotate(
            category_title=Subquery(
                TaskCategory.objects.filter(Q(id=OuterRef("category_id"))).values(
                    "title"
                )
            )
        )

        # Add author info directly to comments:
        task_list = task_list.annotate(
            author_last_name=Subquery(
                CustomUser.objects.filter(Q(pk=OuterRef("author_id"))).values(
                    "last_name"
                )
            )
        )
        task_list = task_list.annotate(
            author_first_name=Subquery(
                CustomUser.objects.filter(Q(pk=OuterRef("author_id"))).values(
                    "first_name"
                )
            )
        )
        task_list = task_list.annotate(
            author_second_name=Subquery(
                CustomUser.objects.filter(Q(pk=OuterRef("author_id"))).values(
                    "second_name"
                )
            )
        )

        # ... snip ...

        # Actually define order:
        task_list = task_list.order_by(*order_by_args).select_related("category")

        return task_list
```

Here's an example on how to add fields created by `annotate()` to serializer:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Compact task info for list views (no body, no author name) with additional fields createdb by `annotate()`:
    category_title, comments_count, new_comments_count, is_favorite, is_acquainted (last three depending on current
    user).
    """

    # These fields will be generated by `annotate()` in TaskListAPI.get_queryset():
    category_title = serializers.CharField()
    comments_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    new_comments_count = serializers.IntegerField()
    is_favorite = serializers.BooleanField()
    is_acquainted = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
            "id",
            "category",
            "category_title",
            "title",
            "is_private",
            "is_archived",
            "attachment",
            "due_date",
            "created",
            "updated",
            "is_completed",
            "completed",
            "comments_count",
            "new_comments_count",
            "is_favorite",
            "is_acquainted",
        ]
```

Comment: Is this going to do a query for each category_title? If so, the performance will not work for tens of thousands of records.

Comment: @dubloons No, the cool part is that `annotate()`translates to single SQL query! That is, all my code posted as example results in just one SQL query! You can check it yourself in your app with `django_debug_toolbar`, for example.